# SQL Query is taking to long to excecute

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query that is taking too long:

```
{SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(5) */
    EXTER.ACE_IT_REGION_ID ,
    EXTER.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
    EXTER.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
    EXTER.TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER,
    EXTER.TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT,
    EXTER.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME AS DATEOFDATA
FROM
(SELECT /*+ use_hash(TAB1,TAB2)  +*/
        DISTINCT
        TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID ,
        TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
        TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
        TAB1.TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER,
        TAB2.TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT,
        TAB1.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME 
FROM
(SELECT     AAA.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
            AAA.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
            AAA.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
            AAA.SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX,
            AAA.TOTAL_DISCOUNT,
            (AAA.SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX-AAA.TOTAL_DISCOUNT) AS TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER,
            TRUNC(AAA.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME)                
    FROM    (SELECT  B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID AS ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                     B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE AS ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                     B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM AS ACE_IT_ORD_NUM, 
                     (SUM(B.ACE_IT_ITEM_PRICE + B.ACE_IT_TAX_AMT)*B.ACE_IT_QTY) AS     SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX,    
                     SUM(B.ACE_IT_DISC_AMT+B.ACE_IT_AUTO_DISC_AMT) AS TOTAL_DISCOUNT,
                     TRUNC(A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME ) AS ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME
            FROM    POSDB.ACE_ORDERS A, POSDB.ACE_ITEM_TRAN B
            WHERE   A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -1) 
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_REGION_ID = B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_LOCATION_CODE = B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_NUM = B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_TYPE = 'IS'
            AND     (A.ACE_ORD_STATUS = 'CR'
                    OR A.ACE_ORD_STATUS IS NULL
                    OR A.ACE_ORD_STATUS LIKE ' %' 
                    OR  A.ACE_ORD_STATUS LIKE '% ')
            AND     (B.ACE_IT_VOID_IND <> 'V' OR  B.ACE_IT_VOID_IND IS NULL )
            GROUP BY B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                     B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                     B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
                     A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME) AAA
    ORDER BY AAA.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
            AAA.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
            AAA.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,   
            AAA.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME) TAB1,
    (SELECT ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID,
            ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE,
            ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM,
            SUM(ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT) TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT
     FROM   POSDB.ACE_PAYMENT_DTL
     WHERE  ACE_PAYD_POSTING_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
     AND    (ACE_PAYD_STATUS <> 'V' OR   ACE_PAYD_STATUS IS NULL )
     GROUP BY 
            ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID,
            ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE,
            ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM) TAB2              
WHERE   TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID
AND     TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE
AND     TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM
ORDER BY
    TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID ,
    TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
    TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM       ) EXTER        
WHERE   (EXTER.TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER = EXTER.TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT)
AND     EXTER.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME IS NOT NULL;}
```

Please give me any suggestions. I have used hints but still not sure why it's taking so much time.
All the tables are huge, about 300,000,000 each.

Before joining the table in tab3 temp table it was taking 5 mins...but now even after 20-25 min it does not return records.

Comment: are you using indices?

Answer (score 1):

slightly cleaned-up for readability of each being subset of next level down.  Also removed the redundant outer query and just added it's WHERE clause to the one inside.  Should be same result

```
        SELECT DISTINCT *
           FROM
              ( SELECT
                      AAA.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                      AAA.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                      AAA.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
                      AAA.SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX,
                      AAA.TOTAL_DISCOUNT,
                      AAA.SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX - AAA.TOTAL_DISCOUNT AS TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER,
                      TRUNC(AAA.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME)  AS DATEOFDATA
                   FROM
                      ( SELECT  
                              B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                              B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                              B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
                              ( SUM( B.ACE_IT_ITEM_PRICE + B.ACE_IT_TAX_AMT)
                                * B.ACE_IT_QTY ) AS  SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX,
                              SUM( B.ACE_IT_DISC_AMT + B.ACE_IT_AUTO_DISC_AMT) AS TOTAL_DISCOUNT,
                              TRUNC( A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME ) AS ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME
                           FROM
                              POSDB.ACE_ORDERS A, 
                              POSDB.ACE_ITEM_TRAN B
                           WHERE
                                  A.ACE_ORD_TYPE = 'IS'
                              AND A.ACE_ORD_REGION_ID = B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID
                              AND A.ACE_ORD_LOCATION_CODE = B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE
                              AND A.ACE_ORD_NUM = B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM
                              AND A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
                              AND A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                              AND (   A.ACE_ORD_STATUS = 'CR'
                                   OR A.ACE_ORD_STATUS IS NULL
                                   OR A.ACE_ORD_STATUS LIKE ' %' 
                                   OR  A.ACE_ORD_STATUS LIKE '% ')
                              AND (    B.ACE_IT_VOID_IND <> 'V' 
                                   OR  B.ACE_IT_VOID_IND IS NULL )
                           GROUP BY 
                              B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                              B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                              B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
                              A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME ) AAA
                   ORDER BY 
                      AAA.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                      AAA.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                      AAA.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
                      AAA.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME) TAB1,
              ( SELECT
                      APD.ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID,
                      APD.ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE,
                      APD.ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM,
                      SUM(APD.ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT) TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT
                   FROM
                      POSDB.ACE_PAYMENT_DTL APD
                   WHERE  
                          APD.ACE_PAYD_POSTING_TIMESTAMP 
                            BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                      AND (   APD.ACE_PAYD_STATUS <> 'V' 
                           OR APD.ACE_PAYD_STATUS IS NULL )
                   GROUP BY 
                      APD.ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID,
                      APD.ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE,
                      APD.ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM ) TAB2
           WHERE   
                  TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID
              AND TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE
              AND TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM
              AND TAB1.TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER = TAB2.TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT,
              AND TAB1.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME IS NOT NULL
           ORDER BY
              TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
              TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
              TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM ) EX
```

To help optimize, I can suggest the following indexes as you do not have any such 
displayed in your post of structures/indexes...  The Payment Detail index is actually a covering index meaning is has the elements for the where, group by and the sum single field.  This way it does not have to go to the raw table pages to do the query.  It can all be performed directly from the indexed fields and each should be optimized for the join and where critreia.

```
table            index on..
ACE_ORDERS       ( ACE_ORD_TYPE, ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME, ACE_ORD_REGION_ID, ACE_ORD_LOCATION_CODE, ACE_ORD_NUM, ACE_ORD_STATUS )
ACE_ITEM_TRAN    ( ACE_IT_REGION_ID, ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE, ACE_IT_ORD_NUM, ACE_IT_VOID_IND )

ACE_PAYMENT_DTL  ( ACE_PAYD_POSTING_TIMESTAMP, ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID, ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE, ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM, ACE_PAYD_STATUS, ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the query using JOINS and ensure the fields being joined on have indexes.

Your revised query should be of this format:

```
SELECT tab1.fld1, tab.fld2
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON (tab2.ID = tab1.ID AND tab2.fld3 = 'xxx')
JOIN tab3 ON (tab3.ID2 = tab2.ID2)
WHERE tab1.fld4 = 'aaa'
and tab3.fld5 > 100
```

This will allow the SQL optimizer to do its job.

Comment: Although the use of ANSI-style joins is recommended it's still perfectly valid to specify the join criteria in the WHERE clause, and the optimizer is quite capable of figuring out what's going on. I agree with your suggestion that OP ensure that appropriate indexes exist.

Comment: I have another some what same query as below which is little more complex that the upper one as this need to lookup lot of table and check the total price and payments. with no 'V' status.It Incluses 5 differnt tables:

Comment: Bob Jarvs: Doing correlated subqueries like this requires SQL to return the entire result set for each subquery, do a cartesian join, and then filter it.  There is no way for the optimizer to help.

Comment: @qwerty13579 Oracle does not need to do a Cartesian join just because a query uses the old-fashioned syntax.  If you look at traces you'll see that Oracle automatically re-writes most ANSI joins into the old-fashioned joins.  Bob's right.  99.9% of the time it won't make a difference.  (There are always a few weird cases where re-writing the syntax style seems to help, but that's the exception and not the rule.)  Although I do agree that it's important to use the newer syntax for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```html
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(5) */
    EXTER.ACE_IT_REGION_ID ,
    EXTER.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
    EXTER.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
    EXTER.TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER,
    EXTER.TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT,
    EXTER.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME AS DATEOFDATA
FROM
(SELECT /*+ use_hash(TAB1,TAB2)  +*/
        DISTINCT
        TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID ,
        TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
        TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
        TAB1.TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER,
        TAB2.TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT,
        TAB1.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME
FROM
(SELECT     AAA.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
            AAA.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
            AAA.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
            AAA.SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX,
            AAA.TOTAL_DISCOUNT,
-- There is no necessary that you write another subquery to finish below sql, you can do it in AAA
            (AAA.SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX-AAA.TOTAL_DISCOUNT) AS TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER,
            TRUNC(AAA.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME)
    FROM    (SELECT  B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID AS ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                     B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE AS ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                     B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM AS ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
                     (SUM(B.ACE_IT_ITEM_PRICE + B.ACE_IT_TAX_AMT)*B.ACE_IT_QTY) AS     SUM_PRICE_PLUS_TAX,
                     SUM(B.ACE_IT_DISC_AMT+B.ACE_IT_AUTO_DISC_AMT) AS TOTAL_DISCOUNT,
                     TRUNC(A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME ) AS ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME
            FROM    POSDB.ACE_ORDERS A, POSDB.ACE_ITEM_TRAN B
            WHERE
            A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
-- you can remove it replace by trunc(A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME) = TRUNC(SYSDATE -1) if there is no index on this column.
--            A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME >= TRUNC(SYSDATE -1)
--            AND     A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_REGION_ID = B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_LOCATION_CODE = B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_NUM = B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM
            AND     A.ACE_ORD_TYPE = 'IS'
            AND     (A.ACE_ORD_STATUS = 'CR'
                    OR A.ACE_ORD_STATUS IS NULL
-- I think it better to replace blow by OR INSTR(ACE_ORD_STATUS,' ') > -1
--                    OR A.ACE_ORD_STATUS LIKE ' %'
--                    OR  A.ACE_ORD_STATUS LIKE '% '
                    )
            AND     (B.ACE_IT_VOID_IND <> 'V' OR  B.ACE_IT_VOID_IND IS NULL )
            GROUP BY B.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
                     B.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
                     B.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
                     A.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME
                     ) AAA
--  remove order by clause in subquery, it's useless.
--    ORDER BY AAA.ACE_IT_REGION_ID,
--            AAA.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
--            AAA.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM,
--            AAA.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME
) TAB1,
    (SELECT ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID,
            ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE,
            ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM,
            SUM(ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT) TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT
     FROM   POSDB.ACE_PAYMENT_DTL
     WHERE  ACE_PAYD_POSTING_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
     AND    (ACE_PAYD_STATUS <> 'V' OR   ACE_PAYD_STATUS IS NULL )
     GROUP BY
            ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID,
            ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE,
            ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM) TAB2
WHERE   TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_REGION_ID
AND     TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_LOCATION_CODE
AND     TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM = TAB2.ACE_PAYD_ORD_NUM
--  remove order by clause in subquery, it's useless.
--ORDER BY
--    TAB1.ACE_IT_REGION_ID ,
--    TAB1.ACE_IT_LOCATION_CODE,
--    TAB1.ACE_IT_ORD_NUM
) EXTER
WHERE   (EXTER.TOTAL_ITEM_PRICE_PER_ORDER = EXTER.TOTAL_ACE_PAYD_AMOUNT)
AND     EXTER.ACE_ORD_COMPLETION_TIME IS NOT NULL;

-- Fix it like this for tempory, please supply explain plan for further.
-- There are so many columns like "ACE_PAYD_STATUS is not null", as you know, index could not contain null value.
-- But I think you can create an similarly index like "create index *** on ACE_PAYMENT_DTL(ACE_PAYD_STATUS,0)" to keep null values in your index.
```

Comment: For more, you should check the last_analyzed time of these table via "select table_name, last_analyzed from user_tables order by last_analyzed desc ". Then analyze your table if necessary.